# Javascript i need to show data in table from dynamic object keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hello everyone I have a array of objects now those objects hold have multiple keys and those keys are dynamic so I have no idea how can I loop through data and show them in the table I am not sure how can I access those when I loop through. I was able to get the object keys into a separate array but don't how to utilize them. Here is the array of data and the array of keys can anyone guide or help me

This is the data array

```
var data = {
"data": [
        {
            "nationality": "Indonesia",
            "gender": "Male",
            "country": "Indonesia",
            "preferred_role": "Customer Service",
            "work_experience": "More than 1 year and less than 2 years",
            "preferred_work_environment": "Open to both",
            "count": 381
        },
              ]
    }
```

This is the keys array

```
["nationality", "gender","country","preferred_role","work_experience","count","preferred_work_environment"]
```

Comment: so, `data.data[0].nationality` would be `Indonesia` ... does that help you undertand how to access the data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create html table dynamically with Javascript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45331539/create-html-table-dynamically-with-javascript-object)

Comment: No buddy it can actually change so if its nationality today in next request it can be something else thats why i took the keys out of them @Bravo

Comment: The problem is i can hardcode the key if its nationality in this array next time it can be something else and so on

Comment: oh, right ... so the keys in the objects could be absolutely anything ... use `Object.keys(data.data[0])` to get the list of keys

Comment: Alright i got the keys here now the problem for me is how can i loop through data and show using thos keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can access those keys dynamically via [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and then perform iteration.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const arr = [{
  "nationality": "Indonesia",
  "gender": "Male",
  "country": "Indonesia",
  "preferred_role": "Customer Service",
  "work_experience": "More than 1 year and less than 2 years",
  "preferred_work_environment": "Open to both",
  "count": 381
}, {
  "nationality": "USA",
  "gender": "Female",
  "country": "US",
  "preferred_role": "Customer Service",
  "work_experience": "More than 2 years and less than 5 years",
  "preferred_work_environment": "Open to both",
  "count": 382
}];

function tableCreate () {
  var myTable = document.getElementById('myDynamicTable');
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  table.border = '1';
  var tblBody = document.createElement('tbody');
  
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tblBody.appendChild(tr)
    for(var j=0; j< Object.keys(arr[i]).length; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.innerHTML = arr[i][Object.keys(arr[i])[j]];
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  }
  
  table.appendChild(tblBody);
  myTable.appendChild(table);
}

tableCreate();
```

```css
@font-face{
  font-family:'Bitstream Vera Serif Bold',
  src:url('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/2468/VeraSeBd.ttf')
}
body{
font-size:90%;
}
table{
  font-family: Arial, serif;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
table tr, table td{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDynamicTable">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of how iterates object's properties:

```js
var data = {
    "data": [{
        "nationality": "Indonesia",
        "gender": "Male",
        "country": "Indonesia",
        "preferred_role": "Customer Service",
        "work_experience": "More than 1 year and less than 2 years",
        "preferred_work_environment": "Open to both",
        "count": 381
    }, ]
};

for (let i in data.data[0]) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

For more details, you can read:

- [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)
- [Iteration protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)

Answer (score 0):

By using object.entries you can get key and values of a object.

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data.data[0])) {
      console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    }
```

By this method you will get array of keys so,you can use them

```
Object.keys(data.data[0])
```

By this method you will get values of a object

```
Object.values(data.data[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippert that lets you list all key/value pairs of all objects contained in a data array:

```js
const data = {"data": [{
            "nationality": "Indonesia",
            "gender": "Male",
            "country": "Indonesia",
            "preferred_role": "Customer Service",
            "work_experience": "More than 1 year and less than 2 years",
            "preferred_work_environment": "Open to both",
            "count": 381
           },{
            "nationality": "German",
            "gender": "Female",
            "country": "France",
            "passion": "coding",
            "preferred_role": "Support",
            "work_experience": "More than 20 years",
            "preferred_work_environment": "virtual",
            "count": 524
           } ] };
           
document.querySelector("table").innerHTML = data.data.map(ob=>
    "<tr><td><table>"
   +Object.entries(ob).map(el=>`<tr><td class="rgt">${el.join(":</td><td>")}</td></tr>`).join("")
   +"</table></td></tr>").join("");
```

```css
.border > tbody > tr > td { border: solid 1px grey }
.rgt { text-align: right }
```

```html
<table class="border"></table>
```