# How do I output a JavaScript object array as a table in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, output

```
var data = new Array(3)
data[0] = [4, "New Orleans",24];
data[1] = [7, "Houston",89];
data[2] = [2, "Los Angeles",47];

document.write(data);
```

I want the code above to output as a table in HTML sorted in descending order based on the first column in the arrays. So `data[1]` should output first, followed by `data[0]`, and then `data[2]`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service**! You have to show that you've put some efford into solving your own problem.

Comment: First, why in that order? Second, why are you using `new Array`, that's not going to be "healthy" for your code? But, I've posted an answer below.

Comment: Three simple steps: 1- Learn how to access array data. 2- learn how to create dynamic elements. 3-learn how to append that/those elements to something. Put them together you will have the array data, create a new table or build towards an existing one...

Answer (score 1):

We'll start with your code.

```
var data = new Array(3)
data[0] = [4, "New Orleans",24];
data[1] = [7, "Houston",89];
data[2] = [2, "Los Angeles",47];
```

First, we need to sort the array so that they print by the order of the first column.

We can sort an array by calling `array.sort(function(A, B) { /* comparator function */ })`. The comparator is any function taking two arguments that returns -1 if A is less than B, 1 if A is greater than B, and 0 if A and B are equal. You want to sort by the first column descending, so it looks like this:

```
data.sort((a, b) => (a[0] > b[0] ? 1 : -1));
```

This is fancy shorthand for saying that if the first element of `a` is bigger than the first element of `b`, return 1 (meaning that `a` is larger); otherwise, return -1.

With `array.sort`, your array is sorted **in-place**; after calling the `sort` method it is permanently sorted (instead of, say, returning a sorted copy of the array).

Now we just create the table. Instead of using `document.write()`, you should manipulate the DOM directly (see this question: [Dynamic creation of table with DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302166/dynamic-creation-of-table-with-dom) for reference).

What follows isn't the most efficient way of doing this, but should be the easiest for a beginner to follow:

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   var tr = document.createElement('tr');   
   var td1 = document.createElement('td');
   var td2 = document.createElement('td');
   var td3 = document.createElement('td');

   var text1 = document.createTextNode(data[i][0]);
   var text2 = document.createTextNode(data[i][1]);
   var text3 = document.createTextNode(data[i][2]);

   td1.appendChild(text1);
   td2.appendChild(text2);
   td3.appendChild(text3);

   tr.appendChild(td1);
   tr.appendChild(td2);
   tr.appendChild(td3);
   table.appendChild(tr);
}
// Adds the table to the page so you see it -- up until this moment, 
// we've just been preparing a table in memory.
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

And voila! The table appears.